# Approximate distance between one lat/long coordinate and a fixed one using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Here

[Distance between two lat,lon points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538324/distance-between-two-lat-lon-points)

I found a very simple and nice formula:

```
d = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + cos(lat1)*pow(lon2-lon1, 2))
```

which I am using like this:

```
SELECT name, SQRT(POW(lat-45, 2) + COS(45)*POW(lon-8, 2)) AS distance
FROM shop
ORDER BY distance
```

and everything worked fine, because I only needed to get an approximate RELATIVE distance.

But then I needed an ABSOLUTE distance, even if approximate... And I started to realize that *maybe* "d" cannot be converted in meters/miles because e.g. there are 180 degrees of latitude but 360 of longitude, so this almost-Pythagorean theorem is "stretching" the diagonal line in a way that messes up a possible absolute calculation... After a while, I gave up and... Here I am.

How can I convert "d" to an absolute distance in meters/miles?

PS: Yes, I will precalculate all the constants in the SQL query in the final version...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Ops, sorry, no no... Just mySQL

Comment: For Postgres you could have used the earthdistance module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL for get the distance in metters check this query, also you can convert it to a function

```
declare @lat1 FLOAT
declare @lat2 FLOAT
declare @lon1 FLOAT
declare @lon2 FLOAT

SET @lat1 = 18.4768047
SET @lon1 = -69.9516518
SET @lat2 = 18.4624464
SET @lon2 = -69.9652686


select (ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*6371)*1000
```

This is an example

UPDATE!!!

I create this procedure for MySQL for get KM, Miles, Metters and yards

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Distance(lat1 FLOAT,lon1 FLOAT,lat2 FLOAT,lon2 FLOAT,unit INT) 
BEGIN  

declare KM INT;
declare MILE INT;
declare METTER INT;
declare YARD INT;

SET KM = 6371;
SET MILE = 3959;
SET METTER = KM*1000;
SET YARD = MILE*1760;


SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(PI()*lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*lat2/180.0)+
COS(PI()*lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*lon2/180.0-PI()*lon1/180.0)))*
(SELECT CASE
WHEN unit = 1 THEN KM
WHEN unit = 2 THEN MILE
WHEN unit = 3 THEN METTER
WHEN unit = 4 THEN YARD END as unit_value)
) as Distance;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Call with:

```
call sp_Distance(18.4768047,-69.9516518,18.4624464,-69.9652686,1)
```

And for SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Distance(@lat1 FLOAT,@lon1 FLOAT,@lat2 FLOAT,@lon2 FLOAT,@unit INT) 
AS
BEGIN 

declare @KM INT
declare @MILE INT
declare @METTER INT
declare @YARD INT

SET @KM = 6371
SET @MILE = 3959
SET @METTER = @KM*1000
SET @YARD = @MILE*1760

SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+
COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0)))*
(SELECT CASE
WHEN @unit = 1 THEN @KM
WHEN @unit = 2 THEN @MILE
WHEN @unit = 3 THEN @METTER
WHEN @unit = 4 THEN @YARD END as unit_value)
) as Distance
END
```

Call with:

```
exec sp_Distance 18.4768047,-69.9516518,18.4624464,-69.9652686,1
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, but I won't mark it as accepted because I was asking if I could get the meters from "d", not to have another query ;) But I will test it neverthless!

Comment: UPDATE: @RickJames  use this for get miles select ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*3959

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

$sql = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`Latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `Longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance
FROM shops WHERE distance >= ".$distance; //distance is in Km

also take a look google maps functions:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#findnearsql

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the approximate distance between two sets of latitude and longitude coordinates using SQL if your database supports spatial extensions or geographic functions. For example, if you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL, you can use their built-in spatial functions to perform this calculation.

Here's how you can calculate the distance between two points in MySQL using the Haversine formula, which is commonly used to calculate distances between two sets of latitude and longitude coordinates:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    (
        6371 * 
        acos(
            cos(radians(fixed_latitude)) * cos(radians(target_latitude)) * cos(radians(target_longitude) - radians(fixed_longitude)) +
            sin(radians(fixed_latitude)) * sin(radians(target_latitude))
        )
    ) AS distance_in_km
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    your_condition;
```

In this query:

- `fixed_latitude` and `fixed_longitude` are the latitude and longitude of the fixed coordinate.
- `target_latitude` and `target_longitude` are the latitude and longitude of the target coordinate.
- The `6371` value is the radius of the Earth in kilometers. You can adjust this value if you want distances in miles.
- The `acos` function calculates the arc cosine.

Make sure to replace `your_table` with the name of your table and add appropriate conditions in the `WHERE` clause to filter the rows as needed.

In PostgreSQL, you can use the `ST_Distance` function with the `ST_MakePoint` function to calculate distances between points:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    ST_Distance(
        ST_MakePoint(fixed_longitude, fixed_latitude),
        ST_MakePoint(target_longitude, target_latitude)
    ) AS distance_in_meters
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    your_condition;
```

In this query:

- `fixed_latitude` and `fixed_longitude` are the latitude and longitude of the fixed coordinate.
- `target_latitude` and `target_longitude` are the latitude and longitude of the target coordinate.
- The `ST_MakePoint` function creates a point from the coordinates, and `ST_Distance` calculates the distance between the points.

Make sure to replace `your_table` with the name of your table and add appropriate conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Keep in mind that these SQL queries will give you the distance between two points in either kilometers or meters, depending on the query. You can adjust the units based on your requirements.